# Recursively remove characters from string until said string matches a fixed width

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

As per the title suggests i am trying to remove characters from the end of a string until the width of the string matches the parent elements width.

The following seems to not work.

```
                    var $list = $('#market_update_content').find('li'),
                    $i = $list.length,
                    $listWidth = $list.outerWidth(),
                    $listWidth = 200;

                    while ($i--) {

                        var $headLine = $($list[$i]).find('.headline'),
                        $headlineWidth = $headLine.outerWidth(),
                        $dateWidth = $($list[$i]).find('.date').outerWidth(),
                        $contentWidth = $headlineWidth + $dateWidth,
                        $difference = $contentWidth - $listWidth;

                        while ($contentWidth >= $listWidth) {
                            $headLine.slice(0, -1);
                        }
}
```

Comment: What about using css `overflow: hidden` for the given parent?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any code in there that will actually change the text() or html() inside the element.

Comment: I'm trying to see how "recursively" fits in here.

Comment: Why are you using a $ at the start of all your variable names?

Comment: $ at the start of a variable when using jQuery.  Used to just use it when referencing a jQuery object but it has become habit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work as long as the headline and date are inline, inline-block or floated block elements.

See http://jsfiddle.net/FGADG/5/

```
$('li').each(function() {
    var listWidth = $(this).outerWidth(),
        headLine = $(this).find('.headline'),
        dateLine = $(this).find('.date'),
        headlineWidth = headLine.outerWidth(),
        dateWidth = dateLine.outerWidth(),
        contentWidth = headlineWidth + dateWidth;

    var html = headLine.html();
    for (var i = html.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (contentWidth >= listWidth) {
            headLine.html(html.substr(0, i));
            headlineWidth = headLine.outerWidth();
            dateWidth = dateLine.outerWidth();
            contentWidth = headlineWidth + dateWidth;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi this does not work in IE6 or IE7 for me :(  Any ideas why?

Comment: Apologies.  This is nothing to do with your JS.  I had to add white-space:nowrap to the parent li element.  Works like a charm now :)

Comment: you could do this in a fraction of the steps, if you were to use binary search to find the correct length value.