# How to cut off text inside a div when it reaches a certain # of characters in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I know there are lots of truncate scripts out there, but I can't use most of them due to integration issues with the cms I am working on.

Basically I must do it this way:

1. get a count of the characters inside a div
2. if count exceeds a certain amount (lets say 10 characters) the text inside the div should be cut off and have "..." appended to the end.

Being terrible at javascript here is my lame non-working attempt:

```
if ($('div.text').val().length > 10) {

   //     

   ($('div.text').append('...');

}
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Similar to one i asked recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106763/recursively-remove-characters-from-string-until-said-string-matches-a-fixed-width

Comment: Do you want it to happen in all the divs with class text ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
if ($('div.text').text().length > 10)
```

or

```
if ($('div.text').html().length > 10)
```

div elements don't have a "value" as returned by val(), but they do have text or html

and then you probably want to truncate the text like

```
var text = $('div.text').text();
text = text.substr(0,10) + '...';
$('div.text').text(text);
```

Comment: yes, with this code I can get it to append the dots once the text inside the div exceeds 10 chars, but how can I cut it off?

Comment: This works really well.  Is there a way to get it to work on whole word endings so it does not cut off in the middle of a word? I am guessing some kind of regex?

Comment: @DannyEnglander Look for a space '_' that is the last space before the desired character count.

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for the CSS property [text-overflow: ellipsis](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html). This is supported by most browsers (even IE7+), but Firefox only supports it as of version 7. For older browser support, you can use some existing [jQuery plugins](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/text-overflow/).

Comment: I'm not sure as of which version it got support, but I tested this in FF 14.0.1, and it works fine.

Comment: Looks like FF supports it as of version 7. I updated my answer, since it was posted before that version came out.

Comment: This answer is exactly what I am looking for and I think it probably the best answer here. Checking for the character count in the string is the wrong approach here. because the strings' size in pixels is also determined by the letters in the string (unless you are using monospace). for instance: "iiiiiiiiii" is shorter than "MMMMMMMMMM" when you aren't using monospace.

Comment: The downside is that it only works with `white-space: nowrap`. It's of no use if you want your text to cut off after 3 lines, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this:

```
$('div.text').each(function() {
    var maxchars = 250;
    var seperator = '...';

    if ($(this).text().length > (maxchars - seperator.length)) {
        $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, maxchars-seperator.length) + seperator);
    }
});
```

[Live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/qe3RV/)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function to the `.text()` method to do your string manipulation like so:

```
$('div.text').text(function(i, text) {
    var t = $.trim(text);
    if (t.length > 10) {
        return $.trim(t).substring(0, 10) + "...";
    }
    return t;
});
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/bjKAQ/).**

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to cut off in the middle of the word, just do the following:

```
  if ($("div.text").text().length > 10) {
    var ttext = $("div.text").text().substr(0, 10);
    ttext = ttext.substr(0, ttext.lastIndexOf(" "))  + '...';
    $("div.text").text(ttext);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
$("div.text").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text();
    if (text.length > 10) {
        $this.text(text.substr(0, 7) + "...");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove the each, see Mark's example above.  .text() iterates over the collection.

Comment: @John, `text()` will only iterate over the collection if it is passed a function (as @Mark does in his answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
var string_limit = 10;

if ($('div.text').text().length > string_limit )
    $('div.text').text($('div.text').text().substring(0, string_limit -1) + '...');
}
```

This checks for the length limit you specify in string_limit. If it's too long, it cuts the text down to the limited length (not accounting for word borders, punctuation, etc - length only), adds an ellipsis, and sets the content to the shortened version.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question and answers.  I used this code for multiples titles and it's helped me:

```
$('span.title-cut').each(function() {
        var title = $(this).text();
        if (title.length > 10) {
        title = title.substr(0, 10) + '...';    
        }
        $(this).text(title);
     });
```